# Get Thread name

Tags: haskell

I´m playing with async operator of Haskell and I would like to print the thread name, but I google about it and I cannot find a way to do it.

Here my code

```
asyncResponse = do
                resAsync <- async operation
                response <- wait resAsync
                print response

operation = do
           threadDelay 5000000
           return "hello async world!!" --> Here Thread name
```

Comment: What do you mean by "thread name"? A thread has a `ThreadId`, but that's not exactly a name.

Comment: Haskell doesn't have an async operator. What module are you using?

Comment: import Control.Concurrent.Async and about the name, in other language based in JVM you normally has a name per Thread

Comment: @Michael_Litchard, specifically, @paul is using the `async` package.

Comment: Maybe I´m blind but I read the async package docu and I was not able to find a thing. Is that bad my question BTW?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `myThreadId` to get a `ThreadId`, which serves as an identifier for the thread, as in the following program:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async

main = asyncResponse

asyncResponse = do
  resAsync <- async operation
  response <- wait resAsync
  print response

operation = do
  threadDelay 5000000
  myid <- myThreadId
  return ("hello async world!!  my name is " ++ show myid)
```

When I run this, it pauses for 5 seconds and prints:

```
"hello async world!!  i am thread ThreadId 5"
```

That's more or less as close as you'll get to a thread "name".  Is that what you wanted?